# Accordion in for loop stays always open

Tags: java, html, css, jinja2, accordion

I have made an accordion with bootstrap but it is in a for loop, so when I click on one item of the accordion, all other items open at the same time. How can I only click and open one item of the accordion?

```
{% for study in studies %}
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
<div class="accordion-item">
<h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
  <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs- 
target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
    {{ study.uid }}
  </button>
</h2>
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria- 
labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-body">
text
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

{% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It was a problem with the fact that the interactive name i was giving the IDs contained weird characters. I just had to loop with

index.loop